# [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver]Can't connect to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, odbc, tableau-api

I have difficulty connecting to MySQL server from Tableau Server.

The error message is:

```
[MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver]
Can't connect to MySQL server on XYZ. 
Unable to connect to the MySQL server "xyz". 
Check that the server is running and that you have access privileges to the requested database
```

I have installed MySQL ODBC 5.3 Driver from tarball distribution in Ubuntu OS, and whitelisted the IP address of Tableau server in MySQL server.

What could be the possible causes for this? And is there any way that I check the ODBC connector was properly installed?

Any suggestion/comments are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Reasons, you could not connect could be different. But the error you've get asks you to check if server is running. It means, it could not find server.

The reasons, it could not find server, could be:

- Server is down (Check its status by `systemctl status mysql`)
- Server is not listening on some port your app connects to
- Server is behind firewall (`sudo ufw allow mysql` command execution required to solve it in this case)
- Your user does not have permissions to access that database, as it states in the error